# gradle plugin 3.0 not building the artifacts

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading to gradle plugin 3.0, our ci build has suddnely start failing with this error :

> cannot access app/build/outputs/apk/*-preKitkat-prod.apk: No such file or directory

Seems like the build is not generating any artifacts.

I tried looking around but didn't find a solution for this.

Is there something extra that I need to take care of while updating the gradle plugin?

it's working fine with gradle 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating to **Gradle** plugin update 3.0.1 and android studio 3.0.1 update it's no longer generates the APK inside the `output/apk` folder it looks like something this for me adding extra **flavour** if present and **debug** folders. something like below.

```
....app/build/outputs/apk/devUat/debug
```

You can try *clear cache and restart* option to clear previous caches. May this will work.

And one more thing to generate the **artifacts** you need to hit **build apk** option from menu.